# Using jq: Only select parents with a certain child key

Tags: json, parent-child, jq

Example json:

```
{
  "version": "3",
  "services": {
    "web": {
      "build": "web"
    },
    "redis": {
      "image": "redis"
    },
    "datadog": {
      "build": "datadog"
    },
    "another": {
      "image": "mysql"
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to return a list of services that have the "build" key, and not the "image" key. Note that the value for the build key isn't something I can key off of.

Output should be: ["web", "datadog"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways that work:

1.

```
jq '.services
    | . as $services
    | keys_unsorted
    | map( select($services[.] | has("build")) )'
```

(Drill down to `.services`, remember it as `$services` for later use, get the list of keys, and select the ones such that the corresponding value in `$services` has a `build` key).

2.

```
jq '.services
    | to_entries
    | map( select(.value | has("build")) | .key)'
```

(Drill down to `.services`, convert to a list of `{"key": ..., "value": ...}` objects, select the ones where the `.value` has a `build` key, and return the `.key` for each).

The second is probably more idiomatic jq, but the first provides an interesting way to think about the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a third approach, notable for being oblivious to the upper reaches:

```
[(paths(scalars) 
  | select(.[-1] == "build")) as $p
 | getpath($p)]
```